# Submit order without payment

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

Im working on a site with woocomerce. I'm pretty sure this has been covered, but I am not sure where (have looked, promise!). Customers must be able to add to cart products... some are priced, others to be quoted on. She then needs to receive the order, check stock availability and get back to them with a price including shipping. So the submit cart should only send an order to her to quote on.Is there any function to make it possible or any other plugins or woocommerce extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the BACs or Cheque methods, the client will not need to pay and you can even add instructions to the customer.
You have option to change the payment method name for any other that you need, then it is quite simple to do this.

[image]